# Spring 4.x and hibernate 4.x basic CRUD application getting warning No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-4

I tried all the trails posted in internet mainly in stackoverflow but coudn't find the exact solution of my application problem.

Please don't mark this as duplicate because warning might be the duplicate but version or something else is causing which is not duplicate here i.e the same answers are no working for me

Warning i'm getting:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Code of my application:

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<!-- <annotation-driven /> -->
<!-- <context:annotation-config/> -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mahender.web.model.Person</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="personDAO" class="com.mahender.web.DAO.PersonDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="personService" class="com.mahender.web.service.PersonServiceImpl">
    <property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></property>
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mahender.web" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Snippet of my Controller(not all the code provided i think this is enough to find the problem)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app")
@Controller
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="personService")
    public void setPersonService(PersonService ps){
        this.personService = ps;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
        return "person";
    }
```

and the jsp snippet of code is:
person.jsp

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/person/add" ></c:url>

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
```

Comment: i guess you need `/app/person/add`? where is `/person/add` mapped?

Comment: @Apostolos that is when i click submit button action will happen but here when i run application i.e Run As-> Run on server this warning is coming in logs and in web 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this on your code.

model.setViewName("person");

model.addAttribute("person", new Person());

and also make sure your .jsp file is inside /views folder

Answer (score 0):

Your requested action is not mapped properly in controller try to changed it to  ***app/person/add***

Comment: Here first application has to load after that /person/add can be clicked i hope you understand how it should work